# Texturing problem

Tags: texture, maya

i recently modeled a tower in Maya, and it's body is funnel in shape (see image 01 below), and when i unwrap it, the uv is curved like this (image 02).  I want to apply a tiling brick texture to it (image 03), but  it seems nigh impossible if the uv is curved like that. Any way to solve this problem?
[image: image 01]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know Maya at all, other than a basic overview. In other graphics editing software, one can apply a distortion grid to an image which would work in this case if your objective was to tile the curved area with the bricks. If Maya supports such a distortion feature, you may be able to accomplish your goal. If one could distort the original brick shape in an external program, can you import the distortion and apply it thus?

Comment: Been a while since I was in Maya, but UVing is pretty conceptually similar in most 3D DCC apps:

in modo I would handle this by unwrapping those specific polys with a different UV projection - in your posted image looks like you projected from top - I'd UV unwrap based on a cylinder for those polys - that should remove all distortion from them.